# Only Match if BOTH Negative Lookahead and Lookbehind fails

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a Regex that checks if a word exists within a sentence if and only if it is not enclosed in single quotes.

I have tried different regex such as:

```
(?<!' )(?i:THEN)|(?i:THEN)(?! ')
```

matches 'then ' | ' then', which should not match.

```
(?<!' )(?i:THEN)(?! ') or (?<!(' ))(?i:THEN)|(?i:THEN)(?!( '))
```

matches 'then' which should not match

I am really stuck as I do not know which Regex works. I have also tried other Regex but it fails to match:

```
' then I jumped.
He said then 'Wow'.
```

Some input would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is it when the word is the only one within quotes, or when it's part of a quoted sentence as well?

Comment: @ClasG Only when the word is the only one within quotes.

Comment: Your requirements are not quite clear. Try `(?i)THEN(?<!' THEN(?= '))` This won't match `' then '`, but will match `' then'` and `'then '`. I would suggest matching what you do not need and match and capture what you need to keep. Then use language specific means to get the final result.

Comment: Could you clarify, which regex engine you are using please? Possible solutions might depend on that fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

This regex will match the word `then` which is not surrounded by quotes.

```
\bTHEN\b(?<!'\s*THEN(?=\s*'))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Some languages do not allow alternation such as `\s?` or `\s*` inside lookbehinds. So if you're using one of those languages then you'll need to get cleaver about testing for spaces.

```
\bTHEN\b(?<!'\sTHEN(?=\s'))(?<!'THEN(?='))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/gS4zU8/1

```
then             matched
'then            matched
then'            matched
'then'
' then           matched
then '           matched
' then '
' then I jumped.       matched
He said then 'Wow'.    matched
SthenS
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  THEN                     'THEN'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    THEN                     'THEN'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    'THEN                    '\'THEN'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```